# Gas fireplace pilot light goes out when fire turns off

Tags: gas, fireplace, pilot-light

I have a Heat and Glo propane fireplace with a constant pilot light. I had to clean the orifice etc. and have a nice blue flame on the thermopile and thermocouple. When the fire turns itself off with the timer switch it makes the pilot light 'pop' off at the same time, resulting in having to relight the pilot every time the fireplace is turned off.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it has thermal couple, if so, you might need to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found dirty burners end up with a little back pressure in the tubes and will flash back blowing the pilot out. If this is what you mean and if you can immediately relight the pilot within a couple of seconds of it going out. Cleaning the burner usually fixes things and in extreme cases I have made a shield out of a pop can cut with scissors to block the puff.
Most of the time cleaning has fixed things have worked for me.